# How to find anagrams using 3 words in a text having a list of words?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text and a list of 60k words.
I need to find anagrams of the text from the list of words using 3 words(lasts in alphabetic order) and the function should return a tuple of the 3 words that build an anagram of the given text.
NOTE: I have to ignore capital letters and spaces that are in the text.

I have developed the function that finds all the words of the list of words that are contained in the text.
but I don't know how to end finding the anagrams.

```
   def es3(words_list, text):
        text=text.replace(" ","")
        for x in text:
        text=text.replace(x,x.lower())

        result=[]
        cont=0
        for x in words_list:
            if len(x)>=2:
                for c in x:
                    if c in text:
                        cont+=1
                        if cont==len(x):
                            result.append(x)
            cont=0


           Examples:
          text =   "Andrea Sterbini"  -> anagram= ('treni', 'sia', 'brande')
            sorted(andreasterbini)==sorted(treni+sia+brande) 


            "Angelo Monti"          -> ('toni', 'nego', 'mal')
            "Angelo Spognardi"      -> ('sragion', 'pend', 'lago')
            "Ha da veni Baffone"    -> ('video', 'beh', 'affanna')
```

Comment: never mind, I did not read the question properly - sorry - forget this comment

Comment: update question with list of words

Comment: i need to find 3 words from the words_list that builds the anagram of the text.

Comment: the list of words is a list of 60k words..

Comment: ok, in the example, "Andrea Sterbini" is the text, right?

Comment: please correct your question grammatically.

Comment: Yes the left str are the texts

Comment: "the result is the list that has all the words of the list of words that are in the text."
What does this mean? Words in  "Andrea Sterbini" are different from 'treni', 'sia', 'brande'

Comment: for result i mean  the list i have devolped as you can see in the code, not the results that should return the function sorry.
anyway sorted(andreasterbini)==sorted(treni+sia+brande). so this is the anagram i need to find

Comment: You can do one thing. Sort the characters in the text and save it as a string.
In a loop, keep taking three words from words_list and then join, sort and save them. Check if these two strings are the same or not?
Is this what you asked?

Comment: in this way i should try all the possible combinations of three words with 60k words

Answer (score 0):

The naive algorithm would be:

- take every triplet of words, and add the item `(sorted letters of the three words, triplet)` to a multimap (a map that may accept more than one value per key: in Python, a reglar map `key -> [values]`).
- sort the letters of the searched text and output the associated values in the multimap.

The problem is that the construction of the multimap has a `O(N^3)` time and space complexity. If N = 60,000, you have 216,000 billions operations and values. That's a lot!

Let's try to reduce this. Let me repharse the problem : given a sequence, find three subsequences that: 1. are non overlapping and cover this sequence ; 2. are in a given set. See your first example: "Angelo Monti" -> ('toni', 'nego', 'mal')

```
sequence    a e g i l m n n o o t
subseq1           i     n   o   t
subseq2       e g         n   o
subseq3     a       l m
```

Find three non overlapping subsequences that cover the sequence is the same problem as paritioning a set of n elements in k groups. The complexity is known as [S(n, k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), which is bounded by `1/2 (n k) k^(n-k)`. Hence, finding all the partitions of n elements in k groups has an `O(n^k * k^(n-k))` complexity.

Let's try to implement this in Python:

```
def partitions(S, k):
    if len(S) < k: # can't partition if there are not enough elements
        raise ValueError()
    elif k == 1:
        yield tuple([S]) # one group: return the set
    elif len(S) == k:
        yield tuple(map(list, S)) # ([e1], ..., [e[n]])
    else:
        e, *M = S # extract the first element
        for p in partitions(M, k-1): # we need k-1 groups because...
            yield ([e], *p) # the first element is a group on itself
        for p in partitions(M, k):
            for i in range(len(p)): # add the first element to every group
                yield tuple(list(p[:i]) + [[e] + p[i]] + list(p[i+1:]))
```

A simple test:

```
>>> list(partitions("abcd", 3))
[(['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']), (['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d']), (['a'], ['c'], ['b', 'd']), (['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d']), (['b'], ['a', 'c'], ['d']), (['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'd'])]
```

Now, I will use as word list some words you used in your question:

```
words = "i have a text and a list of words i need to find anagrams of the text from the list of words using words lasts in alphabetic order and the function should return a tuple of the words that build an anagram of the given text note i have to ignore capital letters and spaces that are in the text i have developed the function that finds all the words of the list of words that are contained in the text but i dont know how to end finding the anagrams and some examples treni sia brande toni nego mal sragion pend lago video beh affanna".split(" ")
```

And build a dict `sorted(letters) -> list of words` to check the groups

```
word_by_sorted = {}
for w in words:
    word_by_sorted.setdefault("".join(sorted(w)), set()).add(w)
```

The result is:

```
>>> word_by_sorted
{'i': {'i'}, 'aehv': {'have'}, 'a': {'a'}, 'ettx': {'text'}, 'adn': {'and'}, 'ilst': {'list'}, 'fo': {'of'}, 'dorsw': {'words'}, 'deen': {'need'}, 'ot': {'to'}, 'dfin': {'find'}, 'aaagmnrs': {'anagrams'}, 'eht': {'the'}, 'fmor': {'from'}, 'ginsu': {'using'}, 'alsst': {'lasts'}, 'in': {'in'}, 'aabcehilpt': {'alphabetic'}, 'deorr': {'order'}, 'cfinnotu': {'function'}, 'dhlosu': {'should'}, 'enrrtu': {'return'}, 'elptu': {'tuple'}, 'ahtt': {'that'}, 'bdilu': {'build'}, 'an': {'an'}, 'aaagmnr': {'anagram'}, 'eginv': {'given'}, 'enot': {'note'}, 'eginor': {'ignore'}, 'aacilpt': {'capital'}, 'eelrstt': {'letters'}, 'acepss': {'spaces'}, 'aer': {'are'}, 'ddeeelopv': {'developed'}, 'dfins': {'finds'}, 'all': {'all'}, 'acdeinnot': {'contained'}, 'btu': {'but'}, 'dnot': {'dont'}, 'know': {'know'}, 'how': {'how'}, 'den': {'end'}, 'dfgiinn': {'finding'}, 'emos': {'some'}, 'aeelmpsx': {'examples'}, 'einrt': {'treni'}, 'ais': {'sia'}, 'abdenr': {'brande'}, 'inot': {'toni'}, 'egno': {'nego'}, 'alm': {'mal'}, 'aginors': {'sragion'}, 'denp': {'pend'}, 'aglo': {'lago'}, 'deiov': {'video'}, 'beh': {'beh'}, 'aaaffnn': {'affanna'}}
```

Now, put the bricks together: check every partition of `text` in three groups and output the words if the three groups are an anagram of a word in the list:

```
for p in partitions("angelomonti", 3):
    L = [word_by_sorted.get("".join(sorted(xs)), set()) for xs in p]
    for anagrams in itertools.product(*L):
        print (anagrams)
```

Remarks:

- `word_by_sorted.get("".join(sorted(xs)), set())` searches the sorted group of letter as a string in the dict, and returns a *set of words* or an *empty set* if there is no match.
- `itertools.product(*L)` create the cartesian product of the found sets. If there is an empty set (a group with no match), then the product is empty by definition.

Ouput (there is a reason for duplicates, try to find it!):

```
('nego', 'mal', 'toni')
('mal', 'nego', 'toni')
('mal', 'nego', 'toni')
('mal', 'nego', 'toni')
```

What's important here is that the number of word is no longer an issue (a lookup in a dict is amortized `O(1)`), but the length of the text to search may become one.